# Function chaining in scala

Tags: scala, method-chaining

I can't seem to figure out how to chain together these functions, any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
// Generic approach to adding flags to a command string
trait UpdateCommandString {
  def update[T](option: Option[T], flagName: String)(implicit command: String): String = {
    if (option.isEmpty)
      command
    else if (option.get.isInstanceOf[Boolean]) {
      if (option.get.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
        s"$command $flagName"
      command
    } else
      s"$command $flagName ${option.get.asInstanceOf[String]}"        
  }
}

// One example of flags (the program I'm using has literally 50+ flags
// so there will be a number of case classes that group them into related
// sets)
case class Flags(cache: Option[String] = None,
  errorlog: Option[String] = None,
  accesslog: Option[String] = None,
  verbose: Option[Boolean] = Some(false),
  auth: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)) extends UpdateCommandString {

  def applyToCommand(implicit command: String): String = {
    // These seem to apply separately, but I want to chain 
    // them together!
    update(cache, "-cache")
    update(errorlog, "-error")
    update(accesslog, "-access")
    update(auth, "-do-auth")
  }
}

// An example of what I'm trying to do
// Given a base command string and a bunch of case classes to apply
// to that string, I'd like to be able to call applyToCommand and 
// get back the modified command string
var command = "run_system"
val f = Flags(Some("asdfasdf"), None, None, Some(true), Some(false))
command = f.applyToCommand(command)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend a complete redesign of your current approach.

Every member of your `Flags` class should be it's own case class, extending a common `Flag` class.

So you can define functions to combine different flags to one configuration. This configuration can than, in a final step, be used to build your result string.

```
abstract class Flag(name: String, parameter : Option[String])
case class Cache(parameter : Option[String]) extends Flag("-cache", parameter)
case class ErrorLog(parameter : Option[String]) extends Flag("-errorlog", parameter)
//...

type Config = List[Flag]

def applyToCommand(commandName : String, config : Config) = {
  def buildString(f:Flag) = 
    s" $f.name${f.parameter.map(" " ++ _).getOrElse("")}"

  val flagsString = config.map(buildString).mkString("")
  s"$commandName" ++ flagString
}

//Now you can it simply use it as I described above
val config = List(Cache(Some("asdf")), ErrorLog(None))
applyToCommand("run_system", config)
```

This makes your code more flexible and easier to refactor.

At last here are some advises how you could modify this design to better fit your needs:

- If you need to group your flags, you can put them in objects or separate files. Or if you want to change their behavior based on the group you can enhance the class hierarchy and add an intermediate layer.
- You can move the parameter from `Flag` down to the case classes, so every Flag can define if it needs parameters, if yes how many and if those are optional or not.
- You could also implement `buildString` at the case classes so every flag can decide how to format it self.
- If you want do add new Flags you simply add a new class and that's it, no need to add anything to an unrelated class.

Comment: Works for me, this allows much more complex reasoning about the flags

Answer (score 0):

As explained @bmaderbacher, I think you should separate the different flags in the different case class.

But to answer your question, you should modify `applyToCommand`:

```
def applyToCommand(implicit command: String): String = {
   var s = update(cache, "-cache")(command)
   s = update(errorlog, "-error")(s)
   s = update(accesslog, "-access")(s)
   s = update(auth, "-do-auth")(s)
   s
}
```

At this point it should be clear that you didn't make the right choice for your `Flag` class.

I'll do something like that:

```
trait Flag {
   def toString: String
}

case class Command(value: String) {
   def add(flag: Flag) = Command(value + ' ' + flag.toString)
   def +(flag: Flag) = add(flag) 
}

case class Cache(size: Int) extends Flag {
   def toString = s"--cache $size"
}

case object Auth extends Flag {
   def toString = "--auth"
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
val command = Command("run") + Cache(500) + Auth
```